# rails carrierwave image upload selects files but inserts nil into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, carrierwave

Thanks in advance to any help everyone.  I'm working with a rails 4 app and want to upload multiple image files using CarrierWave.  My form works but after submit the only update to the database is a new record with the image field as nil.

Here are the server logs at submit (abridged)

```
Parameters: "property"=>{"name"=>"Windsong Ranch"}, 
"images"=>["53a2135761af0826.jpg", "53a2137620ecc597.jpg"], "commit"=>"Edit Property Changes", "id"=>"3"}
```

And when it saves to the database

```
INSERT INTO "propimages" ("image", "property_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["image", nil], ["property_id", 3], ["created_at", "2015-07-15 16:42:41.607696"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-15 16:42:41.607696"]]
```

Here is the form(abridged)

```
<%= form_for @prop do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </p>
 <p>Upload Images<br>
    <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, :multiple => true %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= f.submit "Edit Property Changes", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**image_uploader.rb**

```
  class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  process :resize_to_fill => [1000, nil]

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [100, nil]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end


end
```

**propimage.rb**

```
class Propimage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

**properties_controller.rb**

```
def create
@prop = Property.create(property_params)
  if @prop.save

    if params[:images]
      params[:images].each { |image|
        @prop.propimages.create(image: image)
      }
    end
    redirect_to @prop
  else
    flash[:alert] = "error creating Property"
    render :new
  end
end

def update
  @prop = Property.find(params[:id])
  if @prop.update_attributes(property_params)
    if params[:images]
        params[:images].each { |image|
            @prop.propimages.create(image: image)
        }
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Update successful"
    redirect_to property_path
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Error updating Sponsor"
    render :new
  end
end
  def property_params
    params.require(:property).permit(:name, :purchase_price, :min_investment, :overview, :targeted_irr, :targeted_hold_period, :targeted_yield, :address_street, :address_city, :address_state, :address_zipcode, :sponsor_id)
  end
```

**propimages_controller**

```
  def create
    @propimage = Propimage.new(propimages_params)
    @propimage.save
  end
 private
  def propimages_params
    params.require(:propimage).permit(:image, :property_id)
  end
```

Comment: Please post your `property_params` method.

Comment: Updated to include the params, thanks

Comment: Try `propimages.create(image: image, property_id: @prop.id)` instead of `@prop.propimages.create(image: image)`. If that doesn't work try moving `if params[:images]
      params[:images].each { |image|
        @prop.propimages.create(image: image)
      }
    end` above `if @prop.save`

Comment: Are you currently updating a form?

Comment: The same thing happens on update and on new, the images are in the parameters and then they are nil.  And nothing gets pushed to S3. Making those changes gave the same result as before, thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for the "images" attribute, but you don't permit it to be sent by the request:

```
params.require(:propimage).permit(:image, :property_id)
```

So try using:

```
params.require(:propimage).permit(:image, :images, :property_id)
```

PS: You should really refactor this code though.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. `:images` doesn't belongs to `propimage`, only `:image` does.

Comment: That didn't do it, same issue as before, it brings it through the parameters but when it splits out the two records and inserts nil into the image field.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's been an ImageMagick update that I haven't seen, which is possible, the 'nil' parameter is not valid in your image_uploader.rb

```
  process :resize_to_fill => [1000, nil]

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [100, nil]
  end
```

You must provide a height parameter. I don't think you can just default that out by making it nil. It would be easy enough to test.

```
  process :resize_to_fill => [1000, 1000]

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [100, 100]
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that but it didn't correct the issue.  But I think the problem is somewhere in the uploader.  I have another project that used :resize_to_fit =>[nil, 300] so I know that it is sound.

Comment: No worries. What does 'nil' do as a parameter here? I can't find it in the ImageMagick spec. Always looking for interesting unpublished features.

Comment: On my last project 300px was the height of my row, but user images had different aspect ratios. 'nil' let the width be whatever it needed to be to maintain that aspect ratio.

Comment: Okay. Cool. Thanks for following up and letting me know.